# Morse code decoding and 'NoneType' Error (Python)

Tags: python

I decided to practice Python on CodeWars, so I'm a bit stuck and ask you for help, or give me an advice.

In general, this is a Morse code decoder, I wrote it myself, here's the code:

```
def decodeMorse(morseCode):
    letter, decodedMsg = '', ''
    spaceCount = 0

    morseABC = {'.-':'A', '-...':'B', '-.-.':'C', '-..':'D',
                     '.':'E', '..-.':'F', '--.':'G', '....':'H',
                     '..':'I', '.---':'J', '-.-':'K', '.-..':'L',
                     '--':'M', '-.':'N', '---':'O', '.--.':'P',
                     '--.-':'Q', '.-.':'R', '...':'S', '-':'T',
                     '..-':'U', '...-':'V', '.--':'W', '-..-':'X',
                     '-.--':'Y', '--..':'Z', '.----':'1', '..---':'2',
                     '...--':'3', '....-':'4', '.....':'5', '-....':'6',
                     '--...':'7', '---..':'8', '----.':'9', '-----':'0'}
    for let in morseCode: #Gets each symbol from morseCode
            if let != ' ':  #Checks if the sym is not spacebar
                letter += let #Adds sym to letter
                spaceCount += 1
            elif let == " " and spaceCount > 0: #Checks if the sym is spacebar
                decodedMsg += morseABC.get(letter) #Adds the decoded letter
                letter = '' #Flushes letter var
                spaceCount = 0
            else: 
                decodedMsg += ' '

    decodedMsg += morseABC.get(letter) #Writes the last word
    decodedMsg = decodedMsg.replace('  ', ' ') #Replaces 2 spaces to 1
    letter = ''          

    return decodedMsg 

decodeMorse('.... . .-.. .-.. ---   .-- --- .-. .-.. -..') => HELLO WORLD
```

When I run it in VS Code, it works great, but CodeWars interpreter says there's a

```
Traceback:    
    in     
    in decodeMorse 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Maybe you guys can tell me what's wrong, or help me with optimization. I had troubles with spaces. Three spaces in Morse sentence is just a space between words.

Comment: @BPL , I don't know, I just press "Attempt" button, it does 6 tests and after informs about error. Should I make a screen shot of the page?

Comment: Instead doing that, let's try a much better approach here. You know what's gonna be your input alphabet, right? {'.','-',' '} . In order to reproduce the error, try to generate random strings with this alphabet and feed your function with them till you're able to reproduce that error. And then you'll be able to easily fix it. If you want, I can post a simple example

Comment: @BPL well, your approach worked. decodeMorse(' ') and decodeMorse('') are the cause

Answer (score 3):

`morseABC.get(letter)` can indeed return `None` if the `letter` is not found in the keys of the `morseABC`

Comment: Should I add it into the list? UPD: I've added, keeps informing about error

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when there is an errant space at the end.

```
In [13]: decodeMorse('.... . .-.. .-.. ---  .-- --- .-. .-.. -..')
Out[13]: 'HELLO WORLD'

In [14]: decodeMorse('.... . .-.. .-.. ---  .-- --- .-. .-.. -.. ')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3ea2da5fb8ec> in <module>()
----> 1 decodeMorse('.... . .-.. .-.. ---  .-- --- .-. .-.. -.. ')

<ipython-input-2-e2d6eb0e5152> in decodeMorse(morseCode)
     23                 decodedMsg += ' '
     24
---> 25     decodedMsg += morseABC.get(letter) #Writes the last word
     26     decodedMsg = decodedMsg.replace('  ', ' ') #Replaces 2 spaces to 1
     27     letter = ''

TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

In [15]:
```

Because `get` returns a default value of `None`.

I think it might be better to `split` the string on a *single space*, add the empty-string to single space mapping to your dictionary, then use `join`:

```
In [18]: message
Out[18]: '.... . .-.. .-.. ---  .-- --- .-. .-.. -.. '

In [19]: morseABC = {'.-':'A', '-...':'B', '-.-.':'C', '-..':'D',
    ...:                      '.':'E', '..-.':'F', '--.':'G', '....':'H',
    ...:                      '..':'I', '.---':'J', '-.-':'K', '.-..':'L',
    ...:                      '--':'M', '-.':'N', '---':'O', '.--.':'P',
    ...:                      '--.-':'Q', '.-.':'R', '...':'S', '-':'T',
    ...:                      '..-':'U', '...-':'V', '.--':'W', '-..-':'X',
    ...:                      '-.--':'Y', '--..':'Z', '.----':'1', '..---':'2',
    ...:                      '...--':'3', '....-':'4', '.....':'5', '-....':'6',
    ...:                      '--...':'7', '---..':'8', '----.':'9', '-----':'0', '':' '}

In [20]: tokens = message.split(' ')

In [21]: ''.join(morseABC[token] for token in tokens)
Out[21]: 'HELLO WORLD '

In [22]:
```

Comment: I didn't get a bit, I should write `''.join(morseABC[token] for token in tokens)` instead of `decodedMsg += morseABC.get(letter)` ?

Comment: @VadimKh No, that code replaces all the code starting with your for-loop. The above is an interpreter shell session.

Comment: I don't understand why, but your code doesn't work when I'd placed it under the function.. I tried it line by line in IDLE and it perfectly worked, but not in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you a fix for your algorithm cos you're already close, instead here's a simple technique which will help you to fix your current buggy version. The trick is feeding your algorithm with random strings till you're able to reproduce the codewars website error:

```
import random


def decodeMorse(morseCode):
    letter, decodedMsg = '', ''
    spaceCount = 0

    morseABC = {'.-': 'A', '-...': 'B', '-.-.': 'C', '-..': 'D',
                '.': 'E', '..-.': 'F', '--.': 'G', '....': 'H',
                     '..': 'I', '.---': 'J', '-.-': 'K', '.-..': 'L',
                     '--': 'M', '-.': 'N', '---': 'O', '.--.': 'P',
                     '--.-': 'Q', '.-.': 'R', '...': 'S', '-': 'T',
                     '..-': 'U', '...-': 'V', '.--': 'W', '-..-': 'X',
                     '-.--': 'Y', '--..': 'Z', '.----': '1', '..---': '2',
                     '...--': '3', '....-': '4', '.....': '5', '-....': '6',
                     '--...': '7', '---..': '8', '----.': '9', '-----': '0'}
    for let in morseCode:  # Gets each symbol from morseCode
        if let != ' ':  # Checks if the sym is not spacebar
            letter += let  # Adds sym to letter
            spaceCount += 1
        elif let == " " and spaceCount > 0:  # Checks if the sym is spacebar
            decodedMsg += morseABC.get(letter)  # Adds the decoded letter
            letter = ''  # Flushes letter var
            spaceCount = 0
        else:
            decodedMsg += ' '

    decodedMsg += morseABC.get(letter)  # Writes the last word
    decodedMsg = decodedMsg.replace('  ', ' ')  # Replaces 2 spaces to 1
    letter = ''

    return decodedMsg

random.seed(1)

for i in range(10):
    print('-' * 80)
    test = ''.join(random.choice(['.', '-', ' ']) for _ in range(20))
    print(test)
    try:
        print(decodeMorse(test))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The output will be:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
. .-.--- -..-.-- . -
Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- . .-...  .- .- . .
Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- .-. .--.-  ..  -.
Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -   -  .-- - - .-. 
Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- .-    -.-  .. ---
MA  K IO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 .-.-    - .. ...  .
Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- - ---    .-  .  .-
TTO  A E A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.--  . -----.    -- 
Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.. .  .. -. ...-.-.-
Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
. .--...- . -  -- --
Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

As you can see, with this technique you can easily test these type of algorithms. Remember, algorithm should work with any kind of input, so don't just feed with good cases, feed it with all type of **allowed** inputs. Sometimes is better this type of answers instead of providing directly the solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the method! :D